# Convert longblob to image/jpeg or image/png in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, blob, buffer, multer

I am trying to save some images into mysql. I am using `express, multer` to upload/download image and multer for handling image upload respectively. In my mySQL table, I have the column type as longblob. In node js, I am trying to save the image in the following way:

```
const avatar = req.file.buffer;
const avblob = Buffer.from(toArrayBuffer(avatar)).buffer;
```

In my SQL query, I am saving the buffer `avblob` as `BINARY(avblob)`. The value is shown as `[object ArrayBuffer]`. I am trying to access this image using its id, write to a temporary file and send it as response. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+avatar[0].name+avatar[0].ext, avatar[0].avatar);
    res.sendFile(__dirname+avatar[0].name+avatar[0].ext, (err) => {
        if(err) {
            console.error(err);
            return res.status(500)
                .json({
                    status: 500,
                    message: 'Internal Error'
                });
        }
        res.status(200)
            .json({
                status: 200,
                message: 'Image Sent'
            });
    });
```

where `avatar` is a `RowDataPacket` from mysql where `ext` is either `.jpeg` or `.png`, `name` is a random name, `avatar` is the image blob data. When I send the file back, the response comes as an `ArrayBuffer`. I tried saving it a jpeg file. However, when I tried opening the file, it was corrupted.

So, how do I save and retrieve image blob in nodejs? In my approach, what I not doing or doing wrongly? Finally, when sending the file back as response, how can I inform the client of image file type, jpeg or png, so they can save the file using the proper extension?

**EDIT 1**

I checked the `Content-Type` header and it's image/jpeg. Trying to save the buffer as bas64 encoded and retrieving it also doesn't work.

**EDIT 2**

Since I did not find a solution, I am now just saving the file in a directory and saving the file meta in the database. It is working for now but, it would still be great to figure out if this can be done.

Comment: I have same problem, up up up